# How to easily run local content (javascript, Flash) especially in IE11

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, localhost, local-storage

I've developed interactive content for a client (  [VR Objects](http://scottwitte.com/temp/surfacide)  ) using javascript and Flash (if needed) that they now want to distribute to prospective customers via a flash drive. That makes it local content causing security issues especially with IE. Actually there doesn't seem to be much problem with any browser except IE. True, IE displays the "allow blocked content" button but they fear that is too complicated or scary. And on IE11 in Win 8.1 it still may not work.

The development environment I use has a way around that for testing using an "embedded web server" although all that *seems* to do is produce a localhost address such as `http://localhost:60331/wyj-01xn/output/surfacide_flash.html`. Paste that in the URL bar of any browser on the same machine and you are good. Try it on another machine and no go. So I gather the port address and whatever the `/wyj-01xn/` is about are machine specific. Another possible problem -- it may not work easily with IE11 on Win8.1, but I don't personally have that setup to test.

QUESTION: Is there a way I can produce this same functionality for my client, distributed along with the content on the flash drive, without the need to install some special software (local web server) on each client computer??? The current workaround is to tell customers they should us any browser *except* IE. Client isn't happy.

Answer (score 0):

You could distribute your webpages along with a portable [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/download.html) server, or wrapped inside a [Node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) or [AppJS](http://appjs.com/) package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, user2804989. These will take me a little to digest. My other thought is to wrap the SWF files in a Flash Projector.